# Unable to install Kafka on DCOS

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

Installing Kafka on DCOS without any custom configuration gives following logs

Cluster Configuration is:

8 Private Nodes,
2 Public Nodes

24 Cores Total, 
320 GB Ram Total

All resources are free.

StdErr Output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).  
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdateBlock.initializeStatus(KafkaUpdateBlock.java:196)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdateBlock.<init>(KafkaUpdateBlock.java:50)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdatePhase.createBlocks(KafkaUpdatePhase.java:83)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdatePhase.<init>(KafkaUpdatePhase.java:27)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.scheduler.KafkaScheduler.<init>(KafkaScheduler.java:125)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.scheduler.Main.run(Main.java:70)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.scheduler.Main.run(Main.java:21)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:40)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:77)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:80)
at com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.scheduler.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Stdout Output:

```
ERROR com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.scheduler.KafkaScheduler: Got 1 errors from new config. Falling back to last valid config.
INFO com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdateBlock: Setting initial status for: broker-0
INFO com.mesosphere.dcos.kafka.plan.KafkaUpdateBlock: TargetConfigName: 67004a73-e9a0-4bf6-8e01-9eb52a674c1a currentConfigName: null
Command exited with status 1 (pid: 10171)
```

Comment: Can you share more logs ? Also, did you get this error with a clean install of Kafka ? I'm assuming that you either did not install Kafka previously on this cluster OR if you did you cleaned up the previous state before attempting to install a new one, by following instruction here: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/kafka/uninstall/

Comment: @mohitsoni Thanks it worked after cleaning the previous state from zookeeper.

Comment: @mohitsoni  I had just uninstalled it from the GUI.

Comment: @Kiba then please, please answer the question yourself! As it currently stands it looks as if the problem still exists and there is no solution :(

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I have added the answer, is it correct?

Comment: Thanks, yes this looks fine.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by following instructions here: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/kafka/uninstall

To fresh install Kafka package we first need to clear up 
its previous state from the Zookeeper. Just uninstalling it from the GUI or CLI doesn't work, after uninstall clear the previous state from zookeeper and then fresh install.